# Organize files in client folders

Tags: powershell, file, directory, scripting

I've tons of client files (PDF or Word documents) in one folder. I would like to arrange them in separate folders per client.

The files are named like this: `322123 SF Michael Jackson 3 Shirts Finished`

The destination folder should be: `Jackson, Michael (LastName, FirstName)`

If the destination folder is not there then it needs to be created.

Here's my code till now,

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\acct\Test"
foreach ($File in $FileList) {
$File.Name -match '([0-9]+?)\s([A-Z]+)\s(?<First>\w+)\s(?<Last>\w+)\s(\w.*)';
if ($matches) {
    $Destination = 'C:\Users\acct\Test\Client Files\{4}, {3}' -f , $matches.First, $matches.Last;
    mkdir -Path (Split-Path -Path $Destination -Parent) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    Move-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination $Destination -WhatIf;
}
$matches = $null
}
```

I'm getting error on path matching for destination.

Can someone help me to organize this with a PowerShell script?

Comment: What do you have so far? Please show your code. SO is not a free code writing service.  ;-)

Comment: Also explain what the filename format is and if with all files the 3rd and 4th word is  `FirstName<space>LastName`. The files have no extension?

Comment: Hello :). Stackoverflow is about learning. Its like a hive mind that is here not to help you write code but to help you learn how to write code. We help troubleshoot and can explain topics in a easier to understand way. Give it a try writing this and then ask questions about whats ether wrong that you dont understand. Post examples, This will show us that you have tried figuring it out and need help.

Comment: Are they all in this format? "Number two letters firstname lastname" where the spaces are all consistent.

Comment: Yes, First name is on 3rd position and Last name is in 4th position for all the files. @shadow2020 . Files are in pdf and word format.

Comment: Yes, First name is on 3rd position and Last name is in 4th position for all the files. @Theo Files are in pdf and word format

Comment: Line 1: `$files = (gci "c:\folderwherefilesare\*" -include ("*.doc*","*.pdf"))`
Then below line 1: 
`foreach($File in $files){
    $b = $File.name.split('[ ]')[3] + ", " + $Files.name.split('[ ]')[2]
    New-Item -Path "c:\folderwherefilesare\" -Name $b -ItemType "directory"
}`

Comment: @shadow2020 It worked perfectly for creation of folder, but it doesn't moving the files.Anyways I will work on this.  Thank you for your effort.

Comment: in the foreach statement after the $b variable on a line below it... just do `move-item $file $b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked a few weeks ago so I'm just posting it as an answer to be accepted.

```
$files = (gci "c:\folderwherefilesare\*" -include ("*.doc*","*.pdf")) 
foreach($File in $files){ 
    $b = $File.name.split('[ ]')[3] + ", " + $Files.name.split('[ ]')[2] 
    New-Item -Path "c:\folderwherefilesare\" -Name $b -ItemType "directory" 
    $dir = "c:\folderwherefilesare\" + $b
    move-item $File $dir
}
```